# Replacing recursive with loop

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops, recursion

I am working on an ASP.Net page, and there is tree view in it. In the tree view some nodes have nested nodes like branches. I have data in a list of custom objects in the following format:

> Id, Description, parentId

Right now, I am using a function to recursively add nodes to the tree view. The following is code snippet:

```
private bool findParentAddNode(string id, string description, string parentid, ref List<CustomTreeNode> treeList)
{
    bool isFound = false;
    foreach (CustomTreeNode node in treeList)
    {
        if (node.id == parentid)//if current node is parent node, add in it as its child
        {
            node.addChild(id, description, parentid);
            isFound = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (node.listOfChildNodes != null)//have child nodes
        {
            isFound = findParentAddNode(id, description, parentid, ref node.listOfChildNodes);
            if (isFound)
                break;
        }

    }

    return isFound;
}
```

The above technique works well but, for more then 30K nodes, its performance is slow. Please suggest an algorithm to replace this recursive call with loops.

Comment: Are you sure the recursion is the problem? Unless your tree shape is odd that shouldn't be that many levels.

Comment: I believe `for loops` will be still slow with 30K nodes. Recursive approach is good if you don't call the function with the same parameters

Comment: Note: The you may think the data source list as a table also with three columns and unsorted data.

Comment: I noted it gets more then 1 minute!

Comment: If you do think that the issue is C# recursion you could replace the code with F# (which can optimize using tail recursion).

Comment: To find the reason for slowness, you should use a profiler to find the protion of the code that is comsuming much time. Converting recursion to loop doesn't help.

Comment: @Aron: I never used F#, would you be able to translate the snippet into F#? Thanks.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn: Would you suggest any profiler, if free as well?

Comment: @NadeemJamali Visual Studio should include a profiler. Also, you might want to look into an introductory AI / machine learning textbook, those cover tree search algorithms well. (They'd tell you that for a recursive tree search, iterative-deepening DFS tends to have nicer properties than BFS if you don't know how deep in the tree you should expect the result.)

Comment: see this post [http://stackoverflow.com/q/308816/1174942](http://stackoverflow.com/q/308816/1174942). I've used [JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) before. It is wonderfull but not free.

Comment: It looks like your scanning through the whole existing tree for every node you insert. This will lead to a n^2 algorithm. I'd propose to add the nodes in two passes: first just create all nodes with id and description and put them in a map (hashtable). Then iterate over all nodes again, look up the correct parent in the map and append the node as a child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it recurses down the tree, the code is doing a linear search over the lists of child nodes.

This means that for randomly distributed parent ids, after adding N nodes to the tree it will on average search N/2 nodes for the parent before adding the N+1th node. So the cost will be O(N²) on the number of nodes.

Instead of a linear scan, create an index of id to node and use that to find the parent quickly. When you create a node and add it to the tree, also add it to a `Dictionary<int,CustomTreeNode>`. When you want to add a node to parent, find the parent in the index and add it. If `addChild` returns the child it creates, then the code becomes:

```
Dictionary<int,CustomTreeNode> index = new Dictionary<int,CustomTreeNode>();

private bool findParentAddNode(string id, string description, string parentid)
{
    if ( !nodeIndex.TryGetValue ( parentid, out parentNode ) ) 
        return false;

    index[id] = parentNode.addChild(id, description, parentid);

    return true;
}
```

You will need to add the root of the tree to the index before using `findParentAddNode`.

Answer (score -1):

An iterative version of a breadth-first search should be something like the following:

```
var rootNodes = new List<CustomTreeNode> { new CustomTreeNode() };

while (rootNodes.Count > 0) {
    var nextRoots = new List<CustomTreeNode>();
    foreach (var node in rootNodes) {
        // process node here
        nextRoots.AddRange(node.CustomTreeNode);
    }
    rootNodes = nextRoots;
}
```

That said, this isn't tested, and since it's a BFS, isn't optimal w/r/t memory. (Memory use is *O(n)*, not *O(log n)* compared to DFS or iterative-deepening DFS.)

Comment: It looks better, I'll test it. Thanks millimoose.

Comment: @NadeemJamali You might also look at doing an iterative DFS instead of a BFS but that's a little uglier in C# since you need to modify a list instead of using `foreach`. (And might or might not need to use a `LinkedList` because of the array-based `List` because of the frequent prepends.) A further microoptimisation would be initialising `nextRoots` with a capacity that's a factor of `rootNodes.Count` based on an estimate of the branch factor of your tree to head off resizing.

Answer (score -1):

You can return data in xml format from sql server database using ***for xml***
 then bind it to treeview control.

Comment: -1: that's not really what the OP is doing, he's munging some tree data he already has.

Comment: binding data is not a problem, but the actual problem is to add nodes (those I have in format of records/objects) to tree view and its branches on their right place.